# Why does dependency array in useEffect enters in infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why does dependency array in useEffect enters in infinite loop? I don't see any issues in my code. What can I try to resolve this?
Why does dependency array in useEffect enters in infinite loop? I don't see any issues in my code. What can I try to resolve this?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (cacheStore && !data10?.user) {
      getDog();
    }

    if (data && !data10?.user && !data5?.taskCreated) {
      setData10(data);
    }

    if (logout) {
      setCacheStore(null);
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
    }

    if (!logout) {
      setCacheStore(token?.login.token);
      localStorage.setItem("token", token?.login.token);
    }

    if (tasks) {
      const timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("sndsndsn", tasks)
        setData10((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          user: {
            ...prev.user,
            tasks: [
              ...prev.user.tasks,
              { id: "87877", name: "eduard", completed: false }
            ]
          }
        }));
      }, 4000)
      return () => clearTimeout(timer1);
    }

  }, [
    data10,
    data5,
    tasks,
    getDog,
    token,
    data,
    cacheStore,
    logout
  ]);
```

Comment: Where your useEffect function and dependency array?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    if (tasks) {
      const timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("sndsndsn", tasks)
        setData10((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          user: {
            ...prev.user,
            tasks: [
              ...prev.user.tasks,
              { id: "87877", name: "eduard", completed: false }
            ]
          }
        }));
      }, 4000)
      return () => clearTimeout(timer1);
    }

  }, [
    data10,
    data5,
    tasks,
    getDog,
    token,
    data,
    cacheStore,
    logout
  ]);

Comment: @CoreyCascio please update the question, code is hard to read in comments

Comment: You're setting `data10` in a useEffect that depends on it...? Of course that creates an infinite loop.

Comment: what do you mean? i have edited the post to see the full code. thanks

Comment: Chris G. what can i do then to solve it?

Comment: In your dependency array, you have added `data10` as a dependency, and within the body of the hook, you use `setData10` a couple of times, which causes the rerender, and since this hook listens to changes in `data10`, it will be called again, thus resulting in infinite loop.

Comment: seems to me these are actually a few different effects, try to separate them

Comment: i did that and still the same thing

Comment: If you did that, please update the code in your question